# PIG REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL is not working

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have the below data.

```
•   PRT_Edit & Set Shopping Cart in Retail

•   PRT_Confirm Shopping Cart for Goods

o   PRT-Ret_Process Supplier Invoice

o   PRT-Web_Overview of Orders

o   PRT_Update Outfirst Agreement

PRT_Axn_-Purchase and Requisition
```

The data has special symbols, tab space and spaces. I want to extract only the text part from this data as:

```
PRT_Edit & Set Shopping Cart in Retail

PRT_Confirm Shopping Cart for Goods

PRT-Ret_Process Supplier Invoice

PRT-Web_Overview of Orders

PRT_Update Outfirst Agreement
```

I have tried using REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL in Pig Script as below but it does not work.

```
PRT = LOAD '/DATA' USING TEXTLOADER() AS (LINE:CHARARRAY);

Cleansed = FOREACH PRT GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(LINE,'[A-Z]*') AS DATA;
```

When I try dumping ***Cleansed***, it does not show any data. Can any one please help.

Comment: Try `Cleansed = FOREACH PRT GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(LINE, '^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z]*$')) 
  AS (FIELD1:chararray), LINE;`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Stribizhev. But this only removes the special symbols from input data. bullets are still there in output.

Comment: Thanks Stribizhev. I have figured out. Your script was correct actually the format of bullets got changed when I transferred the text file from a windows machine to CentOS. Thanks for the support.                                   Can you pls suggest some good reference material or website to learn the REGEX in detail. Actually I want to understand the use of the pattern symbols like ^*$ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
Cleansed = FOREACH PRT GENERATE FLATTEN(
      REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(LINE, '^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z]*$'))
       AS (FIELD1:chararray), LINE;
```

The regex matches the following:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^a-zA-Z]*` - 0 or more characters other than the Latin letters in the character class
- `([a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])` - a capturing group that we'll reference to as `FIELD1` later, matching:

  - `[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z]` - a Latin letter, then any characters, as many as possible (the greedy `*` is used, not `*?` lazy one)
- `[^a-zA-Z]*` - 0 or more characters other than the Latin letters
- `$` - end of string

Comment: The thing is that the string is passed to the method that requires a full string match,  so I guess you can even omit `^` and `$` here. To learn more about regex, I can suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: Thank you so much stribizhev. It was very helpful.